# YouTube Embedded Video Shows Developer Options when Click Play Button on Android

Tags: android, react-native, webview, youtube-iframe-api

I am using embedded YouTube videos in my React Native Expo application. The embedded videos are inside a `WebView` from `react-native-webview`. I am having a bit of a weird problem and I am not sure if it is on the YouTube side or React Native side of things.

When I try to click the play button on Android, I get the developer options on the YouTube video. The video does not play and I cannot "click out" of these options.

**What the YouTube Embedded Video looks like inside the WebView when I press play**
[image: What happens when I click play]

Even though I am clearly clicking in the center of the player on the play button, I get this menu. It seems like the Webview is either not responding well to user touch input or it thinks it is a longPress. I am not long pressing the video. When I strip my UI down to just the WebView taking up the entire screen, it works fine. On long press, I see this menu pop up. But clicking the play button everything works as expected.

It seems like once I reduce the size of the WebView (even though the YouTube player is not cut off or squished at all), it isn't responding properly. On iOS, everything is working fine.

**Device Problem Occurs on**
When I started to test on the Samsung Galaxy S7, I noticed this problem. Running the application on a Google Pixel 3 emulator appears to work as expected.

Here is the simple WebView with embedded YouTube video in it.

```
<WebView
     allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
     source={{ uri: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/WOi0vnzcEzA?playsinline=1&rel=0&mute=1autoplay=1&fs=0" }}
 />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I ended up figuring out what was going on. I hope this may help someone in the future.

My WebView was wrapped inside a TouchableWithoutFeedback. For some reason (it is probably correct behavior but over my RN capabilities), it was "blocking" proper user input into the WebView. After I moved the WebView outside of the TouchableWithoutFeedback, everything worked as expected.